# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware treeio.core.middleware.user

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I got this error:

```
[Mon Apr 22 23:45:42 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.88] mod_wsgi (pid=19481): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/projects/treeio/treeio.wsgi'.
[Mon Apr 22 23:45:42 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.88] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 22 23:45:42 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.88]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
[Mon Apr 22 23:45:42 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.88]     self.load_middleware()
[Mon Apr 22 23:45:42 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.88]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
[Mon Apr 22 23:45:42 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.88]     raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
[Mon Apr 22 23:45:42 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.88] ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware treeio.core.middleware.user: "No module named csrf.middleware"
```

I have Django 1.5.1 and Python 2.7.3. I am trying to install Tree.io.

Any suggest?

EDIT:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
    'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'treeio.core.middleware.domain.DomainMiddleware',
    'treeio.core.middleware.user.SSLMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'treeio.core.middleware.user.AuthMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'treeio.core.middleware.chat.ChatAjaxMiddleware',
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.modules.ModuleDetect",
    "minidetector.Middleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.user.CommonMiddleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.user.PopupMiddleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.user.LanguageMiddleware",)
```

The SO: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: Do you have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings?

Comment: Yes, I have django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES;

    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.modules.ModuleDetect",
    "minidetector.Middleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.user.CommonMiddleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.user.PopupMiddleware",
    "treeio.core.middleware.user.LanguageMiddleware",
)

Comment: Could you please include your 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to the answer? Btw, according to docs csrf middleware `should come before any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt with`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment: I Edited the question and included MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: did you try to put `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` as first item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Django version, treeio works with Django 1.3.You can change to 1.3 version writing

```
sudo pip install Django==1.3
```

Or you can work with virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks, but I installed tree.io on Amazon WS; thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

You include `treeio.core.middleware.domain.DomainMiddleware` before `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`. `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` should be in the list before `treeio`

Comment: I changed the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
    ......
)
But the problem is the same..
Thanks for your answer

Comment: I put `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` first and the problem is the same.